# Reference latest Microsoft.Build GAC assembly in F# Interactive?

Tags: f#, msbuild, f#-interactive

How do I reference the latest `Microsoft.Build` in the GAC from a `.fsx`?

When I do `#r "Microsoft.Build"` I always get version `4.0.0`, but I want `12.0.0` to load.

[image]

```
#r "Microsoft.Build"
open Microsoft.Build.Evaluation
printfn "%s" typeof<ProjectCollection>.Assembly.Location
```

This will help me [solve this issue](https://github.com/ctaggart/SourceLink/issues/50#issuecomment-98436214).

EDIT #1:

Doing a fully qualified assembly name did not work for me:

[image]

EDIT #2:

I need the latest which may be different on different systems. I was hoping this would work. :(

```
#I @"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Build\v4.0_14.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
#I @"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Build\v4.0_12.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
#r "Microsoft.Build"
open Microsoft.Build.Evaluation
printfn "%s" typeof<ProjectCollection>.Assembly.Location
```

[image]

The good news is that it is now open source and since none of this works as I want, I'm currently building a fork. I'll probably rename it `SourceLink.MSBuild` to avoid a conflict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>I have never tried this, but I expect you can use the [fully-qualified assembly name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2exyydhb(v=vs.110).aspx):</s>

```
#r "Microsoft.Build, Version=12.0.0.0 ...
```

EDIT:

Okay, so that doesn't work, but this does:

```
#r @"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Build\v4.0_12.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.Build.dll"
```

Comment: I had tried that, but it didn't work for me. I attached a screenshot above.

Comment: @CameronTaggart You're right.  Apparently you have to supply the path to the actual file.  Example above.

Comment: That does indeed work on systems with msbuild 12, but what about systems with msbuild 14? See EDIT #2. I don't think it is possible.